# python ecdsa V,R,S example

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, digital-signature, ecdsa

In python, I know how to create a signature for a transaction using fastecdsa.

```
signature = ecdsa.sign(encoded_transaction, private_key, curve.secp256k1, ecdsa.sha256)
```

The code above gives me R (x) and S (y) values.

How can I obtain the V value (like with Ethereum signatures)? And how can I then verify the signature using the V value?

FYI, I'm creating my own blockchain network.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-examples. Maybe this lib doesn't implement `{r, s, v}` triple. Did you check the docs of this lib?

Comment: That's a simple answer that makes a lot of sense. I tried to force the use of rsv when it simply only produces rs. Thanks